# Linux - Match Filename passed to a script against a wildcard list in a text file and move based off that

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to write a script that will perform the following.  Here is the detail.

1) Files will land into a staging folder

**/tmp/staging**

2) We need to move files to two folders

**/tmp/folder1 (files we dont want but can archive)**

**/tmp/folder2 (files we want to process)**

In order to do this, we need to match the landed file against a list of exlusions that are wildcards such as TST_*, PMP_*, if it matches them, we move the file to folder1, if it does not match not we move it to folder2.

I have tried to setup a find command that will look through the list and move based off what it finds below, what what I really want is to only match the file that I pass as a parameter to the list.

```
FILTER=/tmp/filter.txt
STG=$1 #this is passed as a paremter which is the filename
FOL1=/tmp/folder1
FOL2=/tmp/folder2
FILE=$2

while read line
do
find "$STG" -type f -name "$line" -exec mv -t "{$STG%/*}$FOL2" {} \;"
done < "$FILTER"
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Issue is that rather than moving the file in question as a parameter, it moves other files in the staging DIR that might also match it.  I dont want that to happen.  I only want the file thats being passed as a parameter to be moved based off the list.

Comment: Can you show an example of the command with parameter?

Comment: ./filter_files.sh $filename

Comment: So why don't you just do `mv -t "{$STG%/*}$FOL2"`? `find` recursives the entire directory — it looks like you want this to be based individually on the file. If this isn't the case then you should add the actual values of the variables shown in your script, as it's unclear what they are (eg. `$line`, `$filename`, etc.)